# Does Windows 7 Windows Media Player support H.264 mp4 files with variable frame rate?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, mp4, h.264, framerate

I think the title says it all.

I have a .flv file I am transcoding to h.264 mp4 file. The source uses a variable framerate.

Transcoding the file to an .mp4 file with constant framerate generates a file of almost double size than the same file transcoded to a variable framerate .mp4 but the later does not render at all in Windows Media Player (unfortunately I depend on this player for this files).

Files are 1920x1080 yuv420p, should I play with other options (profile preset and level) or there is no chance that a vfr mp4 file will play correctly in Windows 7 WMP?

Comment: You probably should play with other options. VFR (from what I can tell) is rather unusual. Do you have the option to install additional codecs in order to get it playback?

Comment: @Seth I cannot relay in nothing but a default Windows 7 installation. I am making one last test, but I think the only option is to transcode the files to constant frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here at my findings.

Windows Media Player on Windows 7 does support variable frame rate. It all involves H.264 profiles and levels. In the following table are the profiles/levels I tested:

```
Profile     Level   Works?
High        5.2     No
High        5.0     Yes
Main        4.0     Yes
Baseline    3.0     Yes
```

There was some issues with seek performance, but that is another issue that can be resolved forcing keyframes (http://paulherron.com/blog/forcing_keyframes_with_ffmpeg).

I hope you find it useful :)

P.S.: The ffmpeg command used was:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.flv -preset slow -profile:v high -level 5.0 -acodec copy -vsync 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v "crop=1920:1080:0:0" output.mp4
```